# is it possible to download MySQL data to excel sheet using PHP and that excel sheet having excel formula of each column

Tags: php, mysql, excel

[image: Screenshot-2021-01-29-194446.png]

When we download google sheet it will be downloading with data along with it's formulas.

My requirement is to download data from mysql database to excel sheet.
My data is coming but how I will embed foromula's in that columns. I am using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Basic odbc connection will do this , no code required besides sql.

The result is a [excel table] and you can add new columns with formula and adjust colum sort and table sort

You can manually refresh on demand and optionally have query run when the file opens

There are many ways to do this ( I prefer the legacy method ) here:
https://www.devart.com/odbc/mysql/docs/excel.htm

BTW, you can run any ad hoc sql via this method including insert, update, create table , stored proc, truncate , etc

Comment: Thanks @spioter This way my problem will be not resolve.